# Why is multiprocessing running and the CPU usage drops to 0%, but the results are never released?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, freeze

I have put together what I thought was some simple script to calculate the Moran's Index for each feature in a matrix (Information_Gains_Matrix), with its corresponding weight matrix (Weights_Matrix). I wanted to use pool.map to go along each feature in the Information_Gains_Matrix. The output is just a vector of Moran's Index's for each feature in Information_Gains_Matrix. See code:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial 

def Feature_Moran_Index(Information_Gains_Matrix,Wij,N):
    Feature = Information_Gains_Matrix    
    X_bar = np.mean(Feature)
    if X_bar != 0:
        Deviance = Feature - X_bar
        Outer_Deviance = np.outer(Deviance,Deviance)
        Deviance2 = Deviance * Deviance
        Denom = np.sum(Deviance2)
        Moran_Index_Score = (N/Wij) * (np.sum((Weights_Matrix * Outer_Deviance))/Denom)
    else:
        Moran_Index_Score = 0
    return Moran_Index_Score

def Parallel_Feature_Moran_Index(Information_Gains_Matrix,Use_Cores):
    N = Information_Gains_Matrix.shape[0]
    Wij = np.sum(Weights_Matrix)  
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = Use_Cores)
    Result = pool.map(partial(Feature_Moran_Index, Wij=Wij,N=N), Information_Gains_Matrix)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    Moran_Index_Scores = np.asarray(Result)
    np.save("Moran_Index_Scores.npy",Moran_Index_Scores)
    return Result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Moran_Index_Scores = Parallel_Feature_Moran_Index(Information_Gains_Matrix,Use_Cores=(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2))
```

I'll openly admit my understanding of multiprocessing in Python isn't ideal, but I've used it a lot in the past with success. So I really don't understand why this simple script won't work. Help greatly appreciated. Note, I am aware the Weights_Matrix is not in the script. Its loaded in as a global so it doesn't have to be serialised to each core because it's very large. I'm sorry if this irritates anyone, I know some people get quite testy about the use of globals.

Edit: I've successfully used this exact code on smaller data sets on my local Ubuntu shell (Windows laptop). The problem occurs on a very large data set in a Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: Each process runs in its own memory-space when you use `multiprocessing`, so there are no shared globals — so loading something as a global won't work.

Comment: I'm 95% sure it does work because I've used this exact code on smaller data sets on my local Ubuntu shell. The problem occurs on a very large data set in a Ubuntu virtual machine. I will add this info to the question.

Comment: It was my understanding that globals are inherited to the workers?

Comment: All I can say is that is my understanding of how things work, which has been borne out via hands-on experience using the module. In fact, the overhead of working around this limitation often defeats any potential performance gains.

Comment: Well, we're in the same position then but I've found the opposite results... Either way, it seems this doesn't address my actual question. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: My experience has been that globals are copied from the main context into a private space for each process. So you can pass values to the spawned processes with them, but you can't use them to get results back to the main process.

Comment: The [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) section in the documentation discusses how to share data between processes. Although I note there is a relatively new feature that was introduced in Python 3.8 called ['multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

Comment: @Steve, OK, interesting. However, I have used globals in pool.map processes before and not had this problem. But maybe this is a specific case... Thinking back to my previous usage, the global was only used to find locations of values in the global, and hence was not directly used in the main calculation of the function or the values outputted by the function. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: @martineau, following on from Steve's comment, this may be a solution. It's been a while since I've created a shared memory object and it's almost 1am where I am. I shall try tomorrow. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue I have list of dataframes and I want to process each dataframe seperately so I'm using pool starmap and process starts but cpu drops to 0 after few mins
@ArthurRadley